# Jquery autocomplete problem with focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, focus, jquery-autocomplete

Jquery autocomplete does not work when TextBox control is focused on PageLoad.

Is this a know issue, or is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">



$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#<%=txtSearchTerm.ClientID%>").autocomplete("Acc.ashx", {
        scroll: true, max: 30, selectFirst: true,
        formatItem: function(item) { return item.toString().split("#")[0]; },
        formatResult: function(item) { return item.toString().split("#")[0]; }
    });

    $("#<%=txtSearchTerm.ClientID %>").result( function findValueCallback(event, data, formatted)
    {
        if(data)
        {
            $('#<%=hidOID.ClientID %>').val(data[0].toString().split('#')[1]);
            $('#<%=butSearch.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", false);
        }   
        else
        {
        $('#<%=butSearch.ClientID %>').attr("disabled", true);
        }         
    });

    });


    </script>
</head>


/body>
</html>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#txtSearchTerm').focus();
});

</script>
```

Comment: whats a textBox? , when you make an element autocomplete then some events are set to the element, so u can use see the autocomplete events attributes

Comment: Can you clarify please? Could you post some code that shows this issue? Do you mean that it won't work the moment the page loads? jquery is usually made to fire after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function (){  $('#selector').focus();  });` should be after the `autocomplete()`

Comment: if that don't work then `$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   focus: function(event, ui) { ... }
});` but do check http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ for more information and then check the events tabs

Comment: I have updates my post with additional code. Declaration is in the header, and focus is set on the end.... Not working after I start typing in textbox.

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem as "Jquery autocomplete not firing on keyup unless focus changes" and to fix the issue, I followed the `$('#selector').focus();` suggestion provided by Val and it worked for me. Here is my change

```
$('#inputBox').autocomplete(data);          
$('#inputBox').focus();
```